# Attach a WatiN.Core.Browser instance to a Coypu.BrowserSession?

Tags: c#, watin, coypu

I have a SpecFlow feature which has to populate and submit a (pesky!) Windows authentication dialogue box.

To do this I am creating an instance of WatiN.Core.Browser; I'm doing this as opposed to using Coypu directly as it does not look like I can populate aforementioned dialog with this abstraction framework. However I can successfully do this using WaitN.

I need to re-use the browser session created by Waitn (i.e. WatiN.Core.Browser) with an existing Coypu.BrowserSession (creating a new Coypu.BrowserSession which is associated with this instance will probably be ok too).

"BrowserSession.Driver" and "BrowserSession.Native" are readonly so I can't create the association here.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: I don't think this is SpecFlow related at all. I'd suggest removing that tag.

Comment: @SamHolder I've removed SpecFlow tag, as whilst I am using SpecFlow the problem isn't associated with it.